# How to capture a few words before a certain word in Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

From the string `"Fabulous two, three, or six night Stay For Two With Meals"` I want to capture say 5 words before the word ***'night'***.
In this example I want to get `['Fabulous', 'two', 'three', 'or', 'six']`

I am currently using `s.scan(/(?:\w+)/)` which returns tokenized array:

`["fabulous", "two", "three", "or", "six", "night", "Stay", "For", "Two", "With", "Meals"]`

and then I index through it to find the word 'night'. However I was wondering if regexp can also accomplish this step too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a positive lookahead to your scan to ensure that the word 'night' follows:

```
s.scan(/(?:\w+)(?=.*night)/)

#=> ["Fabulous", "two", "three", "or", "six"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the preceding 5 words by using `/(?:\w+\W+){5}(?=night)/`, which returns `"Fabulous two, three, or six "`. You can then continue to split it into words (could not figure out how to put them in the same regex).